# xamarin.forms authorization without 3rd party libraries

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make authorization in xamarin forms and i dont know how to structure it. I'm using MVVM and for my authorization i wanna use JWT . I want to check if the token is valid then go to certain page . when i put the validation code inside the onappearing method the page is still visible for a very small amount of time and when i put it inside the constructor of the page the navigation doesn't work. How should this authorization should be done?(should i make another transition page with something like an activity indicator ?)

this is the code i use for the token validation

```
public async Task CheckIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        {
            if (!await ValidateToken())
            {
                await _dependencyService.Get<INavigationService>().PushAsync(ViewNames.LOGINVIEW);
            }
        }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: you can hide the page UI and display an activity indicator until your ValidateToken completes.  There is really not "right" answer to this, its just a question of preference

Comment: Can you please tell us what result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i put it inside the constructor of the page the navigation
> doesn't work.

You can call the push service like this in `Main thread`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new myViewModel();

        CheckIfUserIsLoggedIn();
    }

    public async void  CheckIfUserIsLoggedIn()
    {
        if (!await ValidateToken())
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                await _dependencyService.Get<INavigationService>().PushAsync(ViewNames.LOGINVIEW);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked and this is the expected result. i will read more about Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread now.^_^